# Is it possible for one SWF to load another but give it fewer privileges?

Tags: flash, security

From a webpage, I can specify that a SWF should be loaded with "allowNetworking=internal" and "allowScriptAccess=none" to prevent it from modifying the state of the browser.

Is it possible for SWF A to be loaded with no restrictions, and have A impose those restrictions on a SWF B that it loads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to go with "No".  With the exception of ApplicationDomain issues (the inner swf can have a different class library from the external swf, but getDefinitionByName will still work...), there is no real difference between adding a child swf and adding a `DisplayObjectContainer`.  This means that, basically, they are the same swf.